# How to retrieve table row data in php by using an <a>(link)?

Tags: php, hyperlink, row, html-table

I want to implement an inventory table visible below. What I want to know is how to retrieve a table row data, for example when I click the "edit" link from the row of "Item One", I can retrieve it's Item ID "A00". Well, the rest will be up to me after I retrieved that row data. I just want to know first how to retrieve it.

[image: the appearance of the table to be implemented]

Please be informed that I have already displayed the table shown using php, retrieving of table row data by clicking those `<a>` links is the only thing I need to know. Please give me a hint on how to do it, I really need it for our project. This is important to us, any help would be appreciated, thank you very much for your ample time!

Comment: **Please give me a hint on how to do it** : Do a Google search for [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29).

Comment: read this
http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery [Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) and pass your ID as a parameter to the PHP file. Then your PHP file fetches the respective row from your database table.

Alternatively, you can just use jQuery/Javascript to load the content of the current row into the form and 'on update' you can update your database row with the new values. Ajax can also be used in this case so that the page doesn't refresh.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- Using jQuery ajax you can pass the ID of that record to php file.
     Inside that file, You can retrieve the data of that row using ID you passed. For that, use SELECT query to get row data.
     Then pass data to jQuery response to use it in the form to display.

Thanks